# How to remove the delay from an android button?

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a specially effect, if a button pressed. So the the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/clicked"
        />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/clicked"
        />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape"
        />
</selector>
```

shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <padding android:bottom="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

clicked.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <padding android:bottom="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="#2B4881" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

In `activity.xml` I set the file as background for the button:
`<Button android:background="@drawable/background"/>`
But if i press the button, it tooks a while, until the button changes it's color. Can i remove this delay?

Comment: Then you have to create background for unclick as well in drawable folder or else make clickable false for pressed state

Comment: may be the lag because of low memory , try in some other device .

Comment: With unlick I have not problem. If I hold the button, then it tooks a while, until the background changes. Or give me an example if I understand you wrong.

Comment: I use a Note 8, I think it is fast enough:)

Comment: add `drawable/clicked` and `drawable/shape` in your question .

Comment: replace last with `<item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape"
        />`

Comment: Should I replace the the `clicked.xml`  with your code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code , Did you load any high resolution icons/images as background ?

Comment: No but the delay occurs even with the default ripple effect. I think it's a default value from the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code inside selectors

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/clicked" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape"></item>"
```

Comment: This nothing changed. The delay occurs even with the default ripple effect.